# Chrome: howto close the HAR drop zone?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, har

I don't find the way to close the "HAR drop zone" at Chrome's Network tab ?

Clarification: this window tends to open unexpectedly, if I do a drag&drop in the main window, and prevents me from reading the details of the network frames